# Cannot run Junit tests from IDEA 13.0 IDE for imported gradle projects

Tags: java, android, junit, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle project containing some java modules and one android module. Every thing seems working fine, the project builds and deploys on Android devices. 
But, I have a major issue. As I'm using IDEA for TDD. I have to run unit test from the IDE as usual but I get always an error message: Class not found: "[full.class.name]"

-> With dynamic.classpath=true: the generated command is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\bin" -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\lib\util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath9127004204172317095.tmp com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 [full.class.name]

Class not found: "[full.class.name]"
Process finished with exit code 1
```

-> With dynamic.classpath=false: the command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\[UserName]\.gradle\caches\artifacts-26\filestore\junit\junit\4.11\jar\4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\[UserName]\.gradle\caches\artifacts-26\filestore\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\jar\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\[UserName]\.gradle\caches\artifacts-26\filestore\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.1\jar\905075e6c80f206bbe6cf1e809d2caa69f420c76\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\[UserName]\.gradle\caches\artifacts-26\filestore\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\jar\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\[UserName]\.gradle\caches\artifacts-26\filestore\org.objenesis\objenesis\1.0\jar\9b473564e792c2bdf1449da1f0b1b5bff9805704\objenesis-1.0.jar;C:\Users\[UserName]\.gradle\caches\artifacts-26\filestore\org.mockito\mockito-core\1.9.5\jar\c3264abeea62c4d2f367e21484fbb40c7e256393\mockito-core-1.9.5.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 [full.class.name]

Class not found: "[full.class.name]"
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: How do you run unit tests from IDEA?

Comment: In the test class editor hit ctrl+shift+T or right click the unit test file in the project structure view and click run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetbrains support team confirmed to me that this is a major bug and should be resolved by the next release 13.0.1. The release date is not defined yet.

The issue is caused by the Android-Gradle project.

Comment: this is driving me nuts since the EAP. any link to the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to run tests from IDEA just invoke cleanup by running "clean" task from Gradle. Hope this helps.

Comment: This did it for me, too - although I don't understand why a gradle clean would help Idea's class discovery.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error when I didn't put my Java code in the expected default locations: src/main/java and src/test/java.  Once I fixed that, I could run tests from IDEA or the commandline.