# "Class not found" when running JUnit tests from IntelliJ IDEA (Android)

Tags: java, android, junit, intellij-idea

I have a problem when trying to run some Android JUnit tests inside IntelliJ Idea.

My project is an Android Library project using Gradle. When I run my tests, IntelliJ complains with the following error:

```
Class not found: "com.domain.app.ClassTest"
```

But `ClassTest` is present inside the test package.

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'

    compile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        versionName "1.0"
        versionCode 1

        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }

        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

My project structure:

```
src
|_ main
   |_ java
     |_ com.domain.app
|_ test
   |_ java
      |_ com.domain.app
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running tests on Intellij: Class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105264/running-tests-on-intellij-class-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project Structure -> Modules -> your_module -> Paths`.

The value for '`Output path`' should be filled in, but '`Test output path`' will not be. Copy the text that's in '`Output path`', paste into 'Test output path', but change the final '`build/intermediates/classes/debug`' to '`build/test-classes`'. This is because the gradle android test plugin currently dumps all compiled test output (for all variants) into the same directory. This means that currently variants are not fully supported.

[Source](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but just ran into this problem and found that the answer is to store JUnit test files at the following path

*module-name*/src/test/java/

If the directory doesn't exist yet, create it and put your test files in there.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests

Answer (score 1):

### Path with problem character

This is unrelated to the actual question but searchers might come here and it might help. My problem was a class not found error, using a JUnit test ¯_(ツ)_/¯

I'd created a path including directory representing spanned year (2020/2021) in finder and it substituted the forward-slash for a colon (/ → :)

Replacing the colon with an underscore fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the testing library to jUnit4.

Maybe when creating the testing class you choose different testing library instead of jUnit

Answer (score -10):

Try to rename "test" to "androidTest"

`src
|_ main
   |_ java
     |_ com.domain.app
|_ **androidTest**
   |_ java
      |_ com.domain.app`

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09