# libgdx - Intellij class not found exception?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I am using `intellij` for the first time and I haven't been able to run any program. It builds without any errors or warnings but when I run, It throws the `class not found exception`. I have tried everything I could

- Search on stack-overflow.
- I've checked the source folder under the module setup.
- I've checked the run configurations as well

but no luck.

### Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nectarmicrosystems.libgdx.learning.desktop.DesktopLauncher
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

the class source:

```
package com.nectarmicrosystems.libgdx.learning.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.nectarmicrosystems.libgdx.learning.MyGdxGame;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```

[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5goMl.png)

[source structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCG8q.png)

Comment: Have a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105264/running-tests-on-intellij-class-not-found

Comment: How are the dependencies set up? How do you run it exactly?

Comment: Add your code in the post

Comment: Did you set `src` as your `source folder`

Comment: @TobiAdeyinka looks like intellij is picking wrong directory for `source Folder`. Post you directory structure as well

Comment: @BilalShah i just added an image (source structure) is that what you mean? i  cant post more than 2 links yet

Comment: Add `src/main/java/` and make `java` folder as source folder and than try

Comment: @BilalShah just did, same problem still...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to every one that helped, I found the solution. basically the DesktopLauncher class was not getting compiled, so I ran the task through gradle this way:

**look for the Gradle panel in the IDE, open desktop -> Tasks -> other
and then double click on run.**

you only need to do this the first time.

Comment: the run is its own launcher. this doesnt seem to fix the desktoplauncher not found error.

Answer (score 4):

For people who are experiencing this problem, try selecting "desktop_main" in the "Use classpath of module:" drop-down list.

I was getting this error when I selected "desktop" as the module but the error went away when I selected "desktop_main."