# Can't run libgdx project as desktop application

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using intellij idea ide and when I try to run my libgdx project as desktop application I get this message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nivekbryan.labirint.desktop.DesktopLauncher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a same problem so i fixed with this solution. Basically compiler is not getting DesktopLauncher class, so you need to run the task through gradle this way:

Look for the Gradle panel in the IDE,

1. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice, type "Gradle" to open the **Gradle projects** pane
2. Hit the "Refresh all Gradle projects" button if nothing is showing up
3. Expand **:desktop > Tasks > other**
4. Double-click **"run"**

you only need to do this the first time for launch DesktopLauncher class after that you will not get this exception.

I hope it will work for you, cheers.

Comment: where? i can' t find it, do you mean open desktop module? but there is not "Tasks" inside it.

Comment: One more thing, when I run using gradle it works but when I use desktop it doesn't update or follow the new codes.

Comment: Did you set Project compiler output?...refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105264/running-tests-on-intellij-class-not-found

Comment: I guess Android studio has changed too much since then. It's not possible to do 'Expand :desktop > Tasks > other'...

Comment: This works ! Thank you - just follow his instructions ... I'm using the latest Android studio and it worked a charm.

Comment: In android studio 4.1.1, you can do this using gradle pane window. you can access gradle pane through view menu > tool windows > gradle