# IntelliJ IDEA tells me "Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error idea"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I compile a Java project using IntelliJ IDEA, it gives me the following output (and error):

```
Information:Eclipse compiler 4.6.2 was used to compile java sources
Information:Module "sinoWeb" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:2017/3/23 11:44 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5m 32s 949ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

I'm quite confused confused by this! Below are my settings:

[image: enter image description]

[image]

Comment: *A* specific  java project or any project that you try?

Comment: Not really, It's a common project.

Comment: Then try to provide a [mcve]. Not sure if we can help otherwise. Or write a bug report to JetBrains.

Comment: Switch to javac instead of Eclipse compiler.

Comment: In fact, my javaWeb project has some faults in other places. Maybe in other words, it's not a complete javaWeb project, so I have to use eclipse compiler instead of javac to ignore some errors.

Answer (score 171):

1. On **Intellij IDEA Ctrl + Alt + S** to open settings.
2. **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Compiler** -> **Java Compiler**
3. choose your java version from **Project bytecode version**
4. Uncheck **Use compiler from module target JDK when possible**
5. click **apply** and **ok**.

Comment: Ok, so I did the rain dance and it worked, but why?

Comment: I also set the "Target bytecode version" for my module and then it worked without issues.

Comment: @MarthinusEngelbrecht  The bytecode differs according to the JVM version, and hence when you set all to be the same or in this case to be null, it picks from the project settings. https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion

Comment: works like charm.

Comment: for me, on a mac, it was cmd + , to open settings. Or you can click on "IntelliJ IDEA" and then Preferences

Answer (score 90):

I solved this issue by increasing the default value(700) of *Build process heap size* on IntelliJ's compiler settings.

[image]

Comment: This is what solved it for me! Would sit there for 25 minutes and fail otherwise.

Answer (score 52):

I changed my compiler to Eclipse and run my project. Afterwards changed back to Javac and problem solved. I don't know exact problem but it can help who is looking for solution.

[image: intellij java compiler]

Comment: This worked for me also.   No idea why, but I'll take it!

Comment: Unbelievable. This worked for me and I completely lose my mind.

Answer (score 32):

In my case, using Java 11, I had:

```
 public List<String> foo() {
   ...
   return response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<String>>() {});
```

and Intellij suggested I should use `<>` instead of `GenericType<List<String>>`, as such:

```
 public List<String> foo() {
   ...
   return response.readEntity(new GenericType<>() {});
```

I did that in four functions and the project stopped compiling with an internal compiler error, reverted and it compiled again. Looks like a bug with type inference.

Comment: Same pattern here, JDK 11 (11.0.3 and tested 11.0.5), compiled fine in maven, but `Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error` in IntelliJ 2019.2.2; Crash was `java.lang.NullPointerException` on `jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitApply(Flow.java:1235)`. Added the explicit type for the generic and problem went away. Thanks for the posting your case it helped me figure out mine :)

Comment: Thanks. JDK 11 here too. Same problem.

Comment: that was EXACTLY the same problem I was having, thanks for posting tony

Answer (score 25):

In my case it was because of `lombok` library with intellij 2019.2 & java11.

According to [this IDEA bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220430) after workaround idea works again:

`Disable all building from intelliJ and dedicate the build to Maven.`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked and, IMO, is the best solution for Maven-based projects because any manual changes to compiler settings etc. will get reset after your Maven-based project is re-imported.

Comment: This worked but still it does not stop on breakpoints in debugging and never terminate the debugged process.

Comment: This was also happening on a project without Lombok usage, Java 8, idea 2020.3.
But with the Lombok plugin installed.

Doing what suggested fixed it also for me, not sure if it's related or not..

Answer (score 21):

In **JIdea 2020.1.2 and above**,

This is may be the language-level set in Project Structure is not compatible with the target byte-code version.

You have to change the target bytecode version .

1. Go to **Settings** [ Ctrl+Alt+S ]
2. Select **Java Compiler**
3. Select module in the table
4. Change the byte-code version to map what you selected in the previous step for language-level

[image]

**NOTE :**
How to check the language-level

1. Go to **Project Structure** [ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
   ]
2. Select **Modules** sub section
3. **Select** each **module**
4. Under sources-section, **check Language Level**

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 20):

For me the module's target bytecode version was set to 5. I changed it to 8 and the error is gone:

[image: module's bytecode version setting]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Per-module bytecode version settings]

I met the same problem

I solved it by changing the Target bytecode error from 1.5 to 8

Answer (score 6):

You have to disabled the Javac Options: Use compiler from module target JDK when possible.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was response type in `restTemplate`:
[image]

```
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Integer>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        eurl,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        requestEntity,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() { <---- this causes error
        }
);
```

Should be like this:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Integer>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};

ResponseEntity<Map<String, Integer>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        url,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        requestEntity,
        responseType
);
```

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and I'm really glad I stumbled across this answer, and I'm scratching my head why this is. This code here works, too:

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<EventResource>>() {});

It seems that the Java compiler has issues inferring the correct type if you use <>. But still IntelliJ suggests to replace the explicit version with <>. And the error message from the compiler is completely worthless, too. Doesn't even mention the file that causes the issue!

Answer (score 5):

It May is not be relevant to this case, but:

I got this error when I change the Explicit type argument List of:

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<SomeDtoObject>>()
```

to `<>` :

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<>()
```

in `restTemplate` call after Intellij gave the warning to use `<>` instead.

It got fixed when I undo my changes back into the Explicit type argument.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Language Level in the Project Settings (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S) to Java 8 solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

Was facing the same issue with Java 11. Solved by changing language level

**File** -> **Project Structure** -> **Project**

Change *"Language Level"* to ***SDK Default***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed changing my settings. Target bytecode version for equals Project bytecode version.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to update the Open JDK version

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with Community edition 2020.3 on Windows 10 with an older version of the JDK (openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25).

**Updating the JDK to javac 11.0.10 fixed the issue.**

Here's the stack trace that showed up with the error when using openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25:

```
java: compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
java: java.lang.AssertionError
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:155)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:46)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$2$1.setOverloadKind(DeferredAttr.java:172)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.ArgumentAttr.visitReference(ArgumentAttr.java:283)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMemberReference.accept(JCTree.java:2190)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.ArgumentAttr.attribArg(ArgumentAttr.java:197)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:653)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribArgs(Attr.java:751)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1997)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1634)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:655)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3573)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2110)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2006)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitReturn(Attr.java:1866)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCReturn.accept(JCTree.java:1546)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:724)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStats(Attr.java:743)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBlock(Attr.java:1294)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1020)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr.attribSpeculative(DeferredAttr.java:498)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr.attribSpeculative(DeferredAttr.java:481)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr.attribSpeculativeLambda(DeferredAttr.java:456)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode$StructuralStuckChecker.canLambdaBodyCompleteNormally(DeferredAttr.java:900)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode$StructuralStuckChecker.visitLambda(DeferredAttr.java:878)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1807)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode$StructuralStuckChecker.complete(DeferredAttr.java:832)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredType.check(DeferredAttr.java:335)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode.process(DeferredAttr.java:779)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrContext.complete(DeferredAttr.java:626)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Infer.instantiateMethod(Infer.java:214)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.rawInstantiate(Resolve.java:605)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.selectBest(Resolve.java:1563)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMethodInScope(Resolve.java:1733)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMethod(Resolve.java:1802)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMethod(Resolve.java:1776)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$10.doLookup(Resolve.java:2654)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$BasicLookupHelper.lookup(Resolve.java:3293)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.lookupMethod(Resolve.java:3543)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveQualifiedMethod(Resolve.java:2651)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveQualifiedMethod(Resolve.java:2645)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java:3721)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3601)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2598)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$4.complete(DeferredAttr.java:374)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredType.check(DeferredAttr.java:321)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$MethodResultInfo.check(Resolve.java:1060)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$4.checkArg(Resolve.java:887)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$AbstractMethodCheck.argumentsAcceptable(Resolve.java:775)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$4.argumentsAcceptable(Resolve.java:896)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Infer.instantiateMethod(Infer.java:181)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.checkMethod(Resolve.java:644)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethod(Attr.java:4120)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkIdInternal(Attr.java:3913)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodIdInternal(Attr.java:3814)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkId(Attr.java:3803)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3696)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2595)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode.process(DeferredAttr.java:811)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitIdent(Attr.java:3553)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent.accept(JCTree.java:2243)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:702)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitExec(Attr.java:1773)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCExpressionStatement.accept(JCTree.java:1452)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitMethodDef(Attr.java:1098)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:866)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:4683)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4574)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4523)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4503)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Attr.java:4448)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1341)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:973)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:231)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:501)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:353)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:277)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:231)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1441)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1100)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1224)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:1066)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:832)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:419)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:183)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:132)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:132)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:219)
java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
java:   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'project'
javac 11 was used to compile java sources
Finished, saving caches...
Compilation failed: errors: 1; warnings: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Setting -> Build -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
The Target bytecode version of the module is wrong. I set it to 1.8, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `Information:java: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded intellij`.

increased **compiler -> build process heap size**.

[image]

Ref: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003315120-GC-overhead-limit-exceeded

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to go to `help > show logs in files` which opens up the `idea.log` and `build-log` folders something like

`/home/user/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/log/build-log/` where I set the log level to DEBUG in the `log4j.rootLogger=debug, file` in `build-log.properties`

I then ran build again and saw

```
2021-11-27 19:59:39,808 [ 133595]  DEBUG - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - Compiling chunk [module] with options: "-g -deprecation -encoding UTF-8 -source 11 -target 11 -s /home/user/project/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations", mode=in-process
2021-11-27 19:59:41,082 [ 134869]  DEBUG - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - java:ERROR:Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

which lead me to see that this might me related to junit test compilation failing. It turns out I had an older/mismatching of the vintage engine and the jupiter engine which are likely to have different java versions relating in the error above. Changing them to be the same `${version.junit}` removed the error.

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

In short some of your dependency jars may have mismatching java versions.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but in the latest version, the log configuration has changed.
The latest log configuration file is `build-log-jul.properties`, so the configuration method of jul needs to be followed:



```properties
# Configure the level of rootLogger
.level=FINER
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Java compiler to correct "Target bytecode version" which in my case is 8 :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one reason may be jdk version donot macth minimal version of your project.

Comment: Can you give a solution to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of [JDK-8177068](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8177068) issue, which leads to internal error like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitApply(Flow.java:1233)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1628)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:393)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.visitExec(TreeScanner.java:213)
        ...
```

It was fixed in **JDK 11.0.12** and **JDK 14 b14**, so upgrade helped.

Answer (score 0):

I switched across to the cmd line `mvn compile` build and it showed a more meaningful error.

> Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]

Checking my `JAVA_HOME` it was set to 11. Once I adjust my project to use 11 as well I got past this and onto another error (which was solved separately).

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can remove **.m2** folder. Try to reload project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Spring Framework 6.0.0 and JDK 11 as the same time. This is not supported according to [spring framework wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#jdk-version-range). After I degraded the spring framework version to 5.3.24, it solved.

You can check your spring framework version in this way.
[spring framework version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCudJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a mvn clean install recreated the generated-sources in target, it seems that this caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting the `.idea` folder and then reimporting the project again solves this problem. This problem happens to me when I run a unit test.