# Internal error (NullPointerException) intellij Idea raised on compilation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

I am trying to start a project (`java`+`groovy` on `gradle`) after accomplished build. However, I ran into error on start of both `main` or unit test with following stack trace:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.NullPointerException) null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:156)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:50)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:280)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The error arises during pre-start compilling. There is an image of error:

[image]

I have Intellij Idea  2017.3.3 (Community Edition)
JRE 1.8.0_152_release-1024-b11 amd64

Increasing compiler parameter `Build process heap size` does not help.
So, does not help [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274786/723845) to change compiler from `Javac` to `Eclipse` and back with full rebuilds.

Comment: There is already a bug report for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184608 And maybe this workaround will work for you: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184081

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest [EAP (173.4548)](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2017.3+EAP) is fixed the problem (Thanks, @Marcel)