# What is the best sdk version for com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-api-2, android-sdk-tools

I'm facing an issue with the SDK of com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1. With other firebase SDK's like

> com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0

So anyone can suggest me the SDK versions of maps suitable with these two libraries of firebase?

### Update

All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0. This is the error shown after I add that map library 15.0.1.

I have made all SDK of same version but now I get this error

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

**Error Logs**

> Error:Auto build failure: Internal error: (java.lang.NullPointerException) null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:156)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:96)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:42)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:50)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:79)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:280)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:138)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the firebase latest sdk versions from [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions) and play services version from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project).

Your error may occur because, for google maps API, you are using the latest version and using older versions of firebase sdks. These APIs maybe internally relying on each other which maybe the cause of issue.

Comment: I have made all maps and firebase SDKs with the same version. But now I get this error.    **Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details**

Comment: I have updated the Questions with the error logs. Please take a look.

Comment: It seems from logs that error is of IDE. You try cleaning-rebuilding - invalidate caches and restart options. If this also does not help, you should ask another question

Comment: I tried all of your given options couple of times but nothing seems to work for this error.

Comment: There is a issue reported on [jetbrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000789910-IntelliJ-spring-unable-to-build-project) for this and also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438217/internal-error-nullpointerexception-intellij-idea-raised-on-compilation). What I guess from these is, updating your IDE may solve the issue. Else asking another question is the only solution

Comment: If AAPT2 error wasn't fixed by cleaning, one thing it could have been is just that the IDE was unable to delete/clean certain build files when it tried, so the clean operation would have been successful, but the clean wasn't actually. If you still have this minor issue, try go into Project View (or just view your files in Explorer/Finder) and delete build folders, if it says "I can't delete this file(s) because someone(s) is using it" - then hunt down that process(es) and kill it (them)(it's probably JVM), then try to delete those build folders again, then try clean build again