# Why my Gradle Java project doesn't build in Intellij?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-8, ant

I'm trying to start my Java Gradle project in IntelliJ.

I have configured my Tomcat configurations as same as my colleagues.

Their project builds fine.

When I start the build I see the following in the **build** tab.

[image]

It doesn't go beyond the `Writing classes` part.

I don't have any ant tasks in my application. I use only Gradle for dependency management. But for some reason, IntelliJ runs some Ant tasks and tries to 'Write' some classes.

The build hangs after this and a `Memory Exception` occurs after about 3 minutes. Thing is only my project that fails like this. My other colleague's projects work.

Sometimes, I don't get the memory exception. But I get the following exception.

`java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error`

Please let me know any information you need to resolve this issue.

I'm using Java 1.8, Gradle 5.6.2, IntelliJ 2020.2 Ultimate ( The latest )

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried this answer to the similar question : [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081770/9239826)

Comment: Thanks a lot @saibaba.gunturi. When I increased the build process heap size ( default value is 700 ) to 2000 it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by increasing the `Build process heap size` in the `Compiler` settings to 2000 ( The default value is 700 ) as in the following picture.

[image]